# Alexa configuration deployment (staging and product) practice

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Hello I am new to Alexa Skill Kit deployment using [ask-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ask-cli). I just want to know if there are any deployment practices in place where we have different configurations i.e `skills.json` and `.ask/config`

For example, I have a repository `some-alexa-skill` with 2 branches: staging and production.

`staging` has this configuration for the `skills.json`

```
{
  "skillManifest": {
    "publishingInformation": {
      "locales": {
        "en-US": {
          "name": "staging"
        }
      },
      "isAvailableWorldwide": true,
      "distributionCountries": []
    },
    "apis": {
      "custom": {
        "endpoint": {
          "uri": "staging",
          "sourceDir": "lambda/custom"
        }
      }
    },
    "manifestVersion": "1.0"
  }
}
```

while `production` has this:

```
{
  "skillManifest": {
    "publishingInformation": {
      "locales": {
        "en-US": {
          "name": "production"
        }
      },
      "isAvailableWorldwide": true,
      "distributionCountries": []
    },
    "apis": {
      "custom": {
        "endpoint": {
          "uri": "production",
          "sourceDir": "lambda/custom"
        }
      }
    },
    "manifestVersion": "1.0"
  }
}
```

As I can observe `skill.json` should  be "ignored" in the git respository since it will be replaced whenever merges occur during "release to production". I'm thinking of just ignoring `skills.json` and just change it when I want to deploy. But I am also considering the ability to allow others to deploy it in their own machines.

Any suggestions on how should I approach this using `ask-cli`?

Answer (score 2):

Using the API should allow you to control your source and target destinations however you like. Using "profiles" will allow you to keep separate sets of credentials also.

There are 2 different levels of control when using the ask-cli. One is high level, and simplifies creating, cloning, and updating skills. These use the format:

- "ask new ..." or "ask clone" to create or copy an existing skill
- "ask deploy ..." to update parts or all of the skill.

A lower level API is available that allows more specific control. These use the format "ask api ..." and allow you to specify for example the specific file to upload/download to/from. I've found these better for projects with staging, develop, testing branches, etc.

In all of the ask commands, you can provide a profile that specifies the credentials for the Alexa developer account and the AWS account for the Lambda. Use the "ask init" to set these up. I keep separate profiles for:

- my home/hobby projects using my personal accounts
- my work related development/debugging
- my work client projects accessible by our testers and clients.

The Amazon doc is pretty well written, and explains how to use the ask-cli. It just doesn't go into why you would use multiple profiles, etc.

I hope this helps. Start with the Amazon ask-cli [quick start](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html) then follow the links to the reference documentation.

One thing to be careful about is to make sure that you are using the latest ask-cli download. As of today it is 1.0.0-beta.4. You can use the "ask -v" command to display your installed version. There were problems with the deploy command in the earlier 1.0.0-beta.1 version.